# Is there a way to specify the return type of a object function to the React Prop type of another object record?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, type-inference

What I'm trying to do is to define a type like so

```
type Layouts = {
  [layoutName: string]: {
    component: FC<any>; // this any
    props: (props: PageProps) => any; // and this any should be the same
  };
};
```

where the two used `any`s are the same. So the Component Prop Type passed to `component` should be the return type of the function passed to `props`.

I thought a generic might help in this case but don't know exactly where to put it, because the generic type should be specific to the value of `layoutName` and should be infered automatically.

Comment: Where would you use this Layouts type? In a function? As the type for a variable?

Comment: @vera. As the type of an object containing a string as key and an object as value. E.g. ```ts { default: { component: LayoutComponent, (pageProps) => ({ navigation: pageProps.navigation }) }``` where the Prop type of `LayoutComponent` would be ```ts { navigation: string[] } ```

Comment: No, I know what the type is and what you want it to do. I'm asking *where* you would use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think It is better to use a mapped type like this :

```
type Layouts<T> = {
    [P in  keyof T] : {
        component : FC<T[P]>,
        props: (props: PageProps) => T[P]
    }
}
```

And then define the generic parameter `T` as a type, which its keys are `layoutNames` and the value of each key is the `FC` prop type and `props` return type.

```
type MyLayouts = Layouts<{foo: {name: string; age: number}, bar: string}>
```

So `MyLayouts` type becomes:

```
type MyLayouts = {
    foo: {
        component: FC<{
            name: string;
            age: number;
        }>;
        props: (props: PageProps) => {
            name: string;
            age: number;
        };
    };
    bar: {
        component: FC<string>;
        props: (props: PageProps) => string;
    };
}
```